# Suggestions / methods for finding anomalies / outliers in a distribution of payment data

Tags: distributions, outliers, anomaly-detection

May be a failure of imagination on my part, but I'm looking for suggestions on how one might identify subsets of data from a distribution that are strange, anomalistic, or outliers.

More information:  I have a set of payment data for about 2 years.  This data also contains attributes for the entities that the payments were made to, and the number of payments to any given entity is fairly random.  The distribution of the payments looks roughly like a log-normal or gumbel distribution as does the distribution of the average payment amounts to the entities involved.

I'd like to identify entities with unusual payment patterns, or to at least characterize and group the entities based on the distribution of the payment amounts they receive.  We suspect and are interested in identifying entities that may be attempting to extract additional funds out of this system.

I've tried a simple confidence interval, but that is a little unsatisfying as it seems to, as expected, generally pull out the entities on the tail to the far right, and those entities are typically well scrutinized anyway.

Might be too vague / broad a question for this forum, but I thought I'd go begging for suggestions.

Comment: is this related to fraud detection? there must be a ton of literature on anti money laundering (AML) field, since **every** single bank has to do it at least to comply with banking regulations in US. there's a lot of people doing all kinds of stuff with payment activity including machine learning and rules based flagging

Answer (score 2):

My first action would be plotting the data and eyeball if there are data points that fall suspiciously far from all others.

Then, in R I would plot a Residuals-vs-Leverage graph and check which data points fall beyond Cook's distance. Something like this should work:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2) ; plot(lm(payments~1, data=yourdata))
```

It's a standard diagnostics graph for visually assessing whether the data obey to the assumptions of linear models. This method is good for single outliers.

To look for more "systemic" outliers, clusters of data, or multimodality, one option is cluster analysis. You can perform cluster analysis in R using package `mclust`. Here are some details about it: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mclust/vignettes/mclust.html

Also, see the related questions (some with answers) that pop up in the right column of this page. - Cheers